# Avoid console message form package function

Tags: r

I'm using a package function (corenv, from seewave) which create a "please wait..." message in console. As I call it iteratively, that message is very annoying. So, I need a way for:

- From my code, to temporarily ban the console messages

OR

- To access the function code and take off the message line

The following is not my real code, but a very simple one showing the problem

```
require(seewave)
a = seq(0, (2*pi), by=0.01) #simple, unreal example
for (i in sequence(100)){
  x = sin(a*i/3) #simple, unreal example
  y = sin(a*i/2) #simple, unreal example
  corenv(x,y,10,plot=FALSE)
}
```

A very simple question, but I haven't found any solution. I'll aprecciate any help

Comment: Unfortunately, [if you look on line 967](https://github.com/cran/seewave/blob/master/R/seewave.r), it looks like this is printed to the console via `cat`, rather than `message()` (which would be easy to suppress).

Comment: You could remove that line from the function definition and re-run the function definition in your global environment.

Comment: can you not wrap it in `capture.output` .. . ie `capture.output(out[i] <- corenv(x,y,10,plot=FALSE))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sink` to capture the output, e.g.

```
sink("tmp.txt")
z = corenv(x,y,10,plot=FALSE)
sink()
```

You can also wrap it in a function, e.g.

```
## unlink deletes the temporary file
## on.exit ensures the sink is closed even if 
## corenv raises an error.
corenv(..., verbose=FALSE) {
  if(verbose) {
    sink("tmp.txt")
    on.exit(sink(); unlink("tmp.txt"))
  }
  seewave::corenv(...)
}
```